# Erro com código PHP

Tags: php

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login, porém o sistema de mensagem ao digitar email ou senha incorretos está dando erro. Foram feitas algumas alterações na minha postagem anterior, porém o problema não foi resolvido. Os erros exibidos na páginas são:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: cdg in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\index.php on line 69

 Notice: Undefined variable: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\index.php on line 86
```

Segue abaixo o código HTML E PHP com as linhas sinalizadas conforme o erro apresentado:

HTML:

```
<a href="#login" class="btn-get-started"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExemplo">Cadastre-se</a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalExemplo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Entre</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
                    <?php
  //LINHA 69          $cdg = $_GET['cdg'];
                    if ($cdg == 1) {
                        $msg = "Login ou senha incorreto!";
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="modal-body text-md-center">
                    <form method="post" action="valida.php">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email:">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha:">
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><br><br>
                        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                            <?php
          //LINHA 86   echo $msg;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-center">Caso não possuir conta,
                            <a href="#cadastrouser"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSelecionar" data-dismiss="modal">cadastre-se</a>
                        </p>



                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
/* Verifica se existe usuario, o segredo ta aqui quando ele procupa uma 
linha q contenha o login e a senha digitada */
$sql_logar = "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE email = '$email' && senha = '$senha'";
$exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error());
$fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar);
$num_logar = mysqli_num_rows($exe_logar);

//Verifica se n existe uma linha com o login e a senha digitado
if ($num_logar == 0){
    header("Location: index.php#login?cod=1");
} 
else{
   //Cria a sessão e manda pra pagina principal.php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
   header("Location:aluno.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['cdg']` e `$msg` não existe e o seu código primeiro deve verificar se existe pra depois mostrar ou recuperar

Comment: Opa Virgilio, gostaria de pegar esse 'cdg' do php direto, como tentativa de login, como se fosse o num_logar, mas não deu certo

Comment: Então precisa pegar aquilo que existe! o `cdg` você está passando na `url`?

Comment: Não estou, como posso fazer de maneira prática?

Comment: Eu não sei como está fazendo e o que precisa mas, é na url tipo `http://www/logar.php?cdg=1` então no seu código PHP funciona. mas, mesmo assim tem que verificar a existencia com `isset()`

Comment: Consegui tirar o primeiro erro usando um isset, porém o segundo não consegui, quando eu coloco o isset da um erro no código que não abre nem a página.. Preciso colocar um SESSION no php para que quando de errado o login demonstre a mensagem:     $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorreto!</div>";
Como posso fazer?

Comment: Isso que falei acima é refente ao echo $msg no html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o erro, resolvi o primeiro e o segundo, porém a mensagem não é exibida ao usuário final. Segue o código atualizado da parte do html, problema resolvido!:

HTML:

```
<?php
                        if(isset($_GET['cdg'])) {
                        $cdg = $_GET['cdg'];
                        if ($cdg == 1) {
                            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorreto!</div>";
                        }
                      }
                    ?>
                    <div class="modal-body text-md-center">
                        <form method="post" action="valida.php">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email:">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha:">
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><br><br>

                                <?php
                                $msg = (isset($_GET['msg'])) ? $_GET['msg'] : null;
                                echo $msg;
                                ?>

                            <p class="text-center">Caso não possuir conta,
                                <a href="#cadastrouser"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSelecionar" data-dismiss="modal">cadastre-se</a>
                            </p>
```